# How to include PEAR's mail and SMTP functions with YII?

Tags: php, yii, pear

I have set up pear, and previously got stuck at:

```
require_once('Mail.php');
```

I managed to resolve this by fixing the paths in PHP.ini, but now YII is complaining:

```
include(LOGIN.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such  file or directory
```

I don't know which libary to install to get PEAR to pick up LOGIN.php, if that's the problem. It could also be that YII is not allowing the import of LOGIN.PHP because it might have its own? I'm grabbing at straws though. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`YiiMail`** is an availble extension to send mails with or without smtp, This is an emailing extension that wraps `SwiftMailer`. This extension also allows you to create emails from view files.
download this from [here](http://code.google.com/p/yii-mail/downloads/list)

In your config file, include below code in component section

```
'mail' => array(
                'class' => 'application.extensions.yii-mail.YiiMail',
                'transportType'=>'smtp',
                'transportOptions'=>array(
                    'host'=>'smtp.googlemail.com',
                    'username'=>'test@gmail.com',//
                    'password'=>'passwd',
                    'port'=>'465',
                    'encryption'=>'ssl',
                ),
                'viewPath' => 'application.views.mail',
                'logging' => true,
                'dryRun' => false
        ),
```

And in controller action section use something like below

```
$message = new YiiMailMessage;
$message->view = 'registrationFollowup';

//userModel is passed to the view
$message->setBody(array('userModel'=>$userModel), 'text/html');


$message->addTo($userModel->email);
$message->addBcc('someone@gmail.com');
$message->from = Yii::app()->params['adminEmail'];
Yii::app()->mail->send($message);
```

the view `registrationFollowup` resides in mail folder inside views folder, the view path is understood from the config file (`'viewPath' => 'application.views.mail'`)

Comment: That doesn't answer his question though, does it?

Answer (score 3):

This is because of Yii's autoloader, it is setup to find Yii's classes, which is diferent from PEAR's standar, what you need to do, its register the PEAR's autoloader

You can read about this in [the guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/extension.integration)

you can use an autoloader that looks like this:

```
static function loadClass($className){
  include str_replace('_','/',$className).'.php';
  return class_exists($className, false) || interface_exists($className, false);
  return false;
 }
```

PEAR extensions should already be in PHP's include path for this to work

See the [Zend Autoloader extension](https://github.com/yiiext/zend-autoloader-component), to get an idea of how to implement this

Comment: Is it possible to add PEAR without actually copying the PEAR libary? I ask because it has already been setup using "pear install", so I don't want to include the library again

Comment: i have modified my answer to reflect that

Comment: not managing at all. will keep trying. where is that code supposed to go?

Comment: take a look at the extension added in the answer, hsould give you an idea